# Programmatically overlay image on gradient

Tags: xcode, background, uikit, overlay

I’m building out a UI that has a few screens with a gradient background and a tiled PNG (blend mode: multiply @ 9% opacity) on top to create noise.

I've managed to create the gradient programatically with this snippet I found [here](https://medium.com/@dunbar151/ios-reusable-gradient-view-with-title-in-interface-builder-4b8868843687) but I'm struggling to figure out how to edit this to add the PNG over it

```
import Foundation
import UIKit

@IBDesignable class DarkGradient: UIView {
 
    let titleLabel = UILabel()
    
    @IBInspectable var title: String? = nil {
        didSet {
            titleLabel.text = title
        }
    }
    
    override func layoutSubviews() {
        super.layoutSubviews()
        // Necessary in layoutSubviews to get the proper frame size.
        configure()
    }
    
    func configure() {
        let gradient = CAGradientLayer()
        
        gradient.frame = bounds
        gradient.colors = [UIColor(red: 0.16, green: 0.0, blue: 0.54, alpha: 1).cgColor,
                           UIColor(red: 0.26, green: 0.0, blue: 0.88, alpha: 1).cgColor]
        
        gradient.startPoint = CGPoint(x: -0.5, y: 0.5)
        gradient.endPoint = CGPoint(x: 0.5, y: 1.5)
        layer.insertSublayer(gradient, at: 0)
        
        
    }
}
```

Grateful for any help, all the answers I've found have been overlaying gradients over images.

Comment: There is no png in your code so it is unclear what you've got or what you want to do.

Comment: @matt The problem is I have no idea where to add the code to achieve this. I've managed to do it in runtime and it looks like this 

`Image("Noise Texture")
                .resizable(resizingMode: .tile)
                .ignoresSafeArea()
                .opacity(0.09)
                .blendMode(.multiply)`

But I can't figure out where to place this into the the code above so I can easily reuse it each time I need it

Comment: That looks like SwiftUI code. But you are using UIKit, not SwiftUI. So it is now even less clear what the goal is. Assuming UIKit, if your goal was to show a tiled image why didn't you make this a UIImageView? A plain UIView doesn't magically give you a place to add an image; a UIImageView does (hence the name).

Comment: I suggest you reverse your direction and forget the gradient, and instead concentrate on showing the tiled image. Adding the gradient behind it will be easy after that.